# How to squash a div vertically and keep element below 100% on screen

Tags: html, css

So I have this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/nUwgX/ which has a little arrow at the bottom. What I'd like to happen is when the window get's resized is to keep the arrow about 15% from the bottom of the screen but I'm not sure how I'd do that. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**:

```
<div class = "container">

    <div class = "top-wrapper">
        <a id = "name" href = "#">Bigfoot Games</a>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom-wrapper">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: #0f0f0f;
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;            
}

.top-wrapper:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0);
    border-top-color: #0f0f0f;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}

#name {
    display: table-cell;   
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto 0;
}

.bottom-wrapper {
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Edit: Okay, so saying that I wanted the arrow about 15% above is not what I meant! Ha! What I mean is, I want the .top-wrapper to be 100% so that it covers the whole window, and you scroll down to see the .bottom-wrapper - however when the screen is resized (other than my 1920 x 1080 resolution) the arrow get's hidden just out of sight, what I'd like is the arrow to be visible regardless of resolution and have the look (in terms of padding/distance) as a 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Comment: Do you want `.container` to be 100% of the screen size? If so, then is `.bottom-wrapper` suppose to be visible at the bottom of the screen? Please clarify.  Thank you.

Comment: So basically you want your `.top-wrapper` to be `85%` high and not `100%` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the css of .top-wrapper to only take up 85%, that leaves 15% for the "arrow" on the bottom to take up.

```
.top-wrapper {
    ...
    height: 85%;
    ...
}
```

see the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nUwgX/1/

Comment: Thanks, seems to get what I'm going for!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.top-wrapper height` to `85%`

I changed just that in the jsfiddle and it maintains when the screen is resized. If that isn't what you are looking for, please elaborate on the question.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your bottom-wrapper at the bottom fixed position ...

Replace your `.bottom-wrapper` class with below

```
.bottom-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bottom-wrapper p{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Then change `.top-wrapper:after` to `.bottom-wrapper:before`